# centOS 7 screen resolution - HyperV hosted

Tags: linux, centos, hyper-v

Just spun up centOS 7 in Hyper V and the screen resolution is  1152:864. The display is 'Unknown Display', how do I fix that and get the resolution higher? 1920x1080 at least but preferably higher.

Comment: You might get more answers from [Super user](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: thanks! I will post there and see if anybody can provide some details

Answer (score 2):

grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1600x1200"

Run this command. Select resolution based on aspect ratio what you see. For me it was 4:3. The maximum allowed in my case was 1600x1200. Google for resolutions list based on aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Did you configured GPU support on Hyper-V ? This problem sounds like your Hype-V is trying to install only basic driver/software, so I'm suggesting you to check first of all Hyper-V setting more carefully.

This link may be helpful for you [--> READ ME](http://techgenix.com/enabling-physical-gpus-hyper/)

Comment: I saw your link earlier today and it looked like it may help. came back now and getting a 502 error :( After some searching, my GPU does not support RemoteFX so I may be out of luck from the HV side. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a similar issue.Although the RemoteFx is enabled , I still get the display is 'Unknown Display'.